# Is there a way to check if a given string, when run with eval() actually can run in the python interpreter?

Tags: python, optimization, artificial-intelligence, eval, interpreter

I have a list of strings and i figured there might be a way for the parent program to tell if one of these child programs compiled successfully in the python interpreter when using eval() instead of just stopping the program. if there's any way to tell without stopping the script it would be a huge help...

Comment: what about `try`-`except`?

Comment: There is a difference between "will it run" and "do I want it to run" though ;)

Comment: You should look up the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9803475/674039

Answer (score 1):

You may find the "compile" function useful:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile

Comment: Safest to use [ast.parse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) - which is the equiv. to `compile(source, filename, mode, ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)`

Comment: @JonClements: An alternative, yes, and shorter too.  But why safer?